# Laravel get user browser and platform from user_agent column in session table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

laravel : `8.8`

laravel save user agent in session table like :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36
```

this is windows user with chrome browser.

I want to get just user browser and platform from it , How can I do it accurately?

I check [jenssegers/agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent) package and its awesome , but for that i need to add `platform` and `browser` column to session table , that is no problem and the problem is just  the way i want to save it that i try this ways :

1- use `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` Event , that means when user login events fired i will save the platform and browser , i have no problem in implementation the issue in this case is in `Login` event its not saved the session recored yet!! and i coudln't update the recored.
I use the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated` event too but this event didn't run for me at all.

2- use the laravel authenticated method :

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    dd("hi");
}
```

that you can do something after user login , but because i use some separated login methods and it will not run for all of them.

what do you suggest?

thanks in advance.